# Load custom ribbon for ExcelDna .xll addin

Tags: c#, excel, ribbon, udf, excel-dna

I have a Visual studio project to create a *.xll* addin.

In that project I have a *Main.cs* file and a *Functions.cs* file.

The *Functions.cs* file stores the UDFs that will be used in Excel.

I had another project to create a ribbon for excel. In that project was a *Ribbon.xml* and *Ribbon.cs* file. I moved those 2 files to the *.xll* project.

But I have no idea what to do to so that when the user installs the *.xll* file to their Excel, the custom ribbon tab will show as well.

**By the way**, I'm a beginner and I'm doing this for an internship. So either I can't really find any discussions on this or I do not understand what people are really discussing. So I apologise in advanced for questions that may seem very simple to you.

Answer (score 2):

To add a ribbon to your Excel-DNA add-in, you need to add a public class that derives from `ExcelDna.Integration.CutomUI.ExcelRibbon`. When loading the add-in, Excel-DNA will find and instantiate an object of this type.

To provide the xml, you override the `GetCustomUI(...)` method, and other callbacks are public methods in this class.

Excel-DNA also supports putting the ribbon xml in the .dna file (that's just an alternative to implementing `GetCustomUI(...)`). The examples you find on GitHub use this approach as it's a bit easier when making a single file example. (The examples are here: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/Ribbon/TestCSharp.dna)

For documentation on the xml schema and signatures of the callback functions, you can look on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(office.12).aspx (3 parts)